# C++ library for reading data matrix code

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, barcode

I am looking for a C++ library for reading data matrix codes, specifically ECC 200 codes (so not QR codes). I have found [libdmtx](http://www.libdmtx.org/) and [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/InterestingLinks). zxing is java, but there seems to be a C++ port. Does anyone have experience with reading ECC 200 codes with these libraries, or possibly with other libraries?

Answer (score 1):

The DM support in the C++ port of ZXing is up to date with the Java (not true of many of the 1D codes). It's not enabled by default in the test apps but is easy to enable (and [will be enabled by default in the future.](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1208))

I don't have any personal experience with actually using the DM decoder but it is included in the test suites and I believe available in the Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real answer then.
I have used both libdmtx and libzxing succesfully. Libdmtx was more straightforward, because it's limited to datamatrices. In my experpience the results were, strangely enough, not always deterministic.
Libzxing is fine as well, but when you do real production (millions or readouts) it will crash sometimes due to the fact that memory management is not perfect. It's really good, but not perfect for a real production environment.

Both the libraries, libzxing and libdmtx require you to have the datamatrix deadcenter of the image and quite large. That means you need to do pre-localisation yourself.
I managed to do this by just using image routines and looking for the 'L' shape and then some smartness with a minimal-area squared bounding box, etc etc. Then the decoding and error correciton step itself i used from libzxing, which still isnt perfect.

If you go for a production environment, either do everything yourself within your own contraints, and if you are not comfortable with doing that, use a paid package, which in turn are never perfectly suited for your application and cost money.

The best port of libzxing-cpp is that of user glassenchidna. https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to use libdmtx
http://www.libdmtx.org/

It has support for all kinds of interfaces. It seems to have good reviews here and in other places….

(But I am looking for help on building the utilities :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since no "real" answer was posted to my question, at least no answer from someone with experience with one of these libraries for reading 2D matrix codes, I thought I will post my own experience.

I tried both libraries and both could read codes, but the performance was not good enough for my situations. In my situation the codes are frequently not "perfect", Dots can be missing, have different size, and code can be a bit skewed. Both libraries had problems reading these codes.

At the end I used a commercial (not free) library, [Sapera](http://www.teledynedalsa.com/imaging/products/software/sapera/). Sapera was able to read the non-perfect codes much better. I used Sapera because it was used at my company in the past, but it is quite possible that other commercial machine vision libraries (like Halcon) also perform well.

Answer (score 0):

I have exensively used Halcon, including for Decoding DataMatrix. I can tell you that it works really well. Even with distortions caused by, for example, reading off a circular body, or skewed prints, it still is able to read them very well, in a short amount of time.

The only downside, and a big one, is the price. The runtime license is very expensive, and you need a development license before you can purcahse a runtime license, which is even more expensive. Unless you project has enough funds, this might not be an option due to this reason. Good luck!